Is it valid to translate answers which are provided only in Italian?
I'd like to improve the usefulness of certain Italian-only answers by translating them into English — is there a consensus on whether this is welcome, encouraged or discouraged?
I don't want to step on or misinterpret the author's intentions, but I feel like learners who are curious but not at the level to understand the untranslated question might benefit.

I believe that, in general, the idea is that the answer is in the same language as the question. Do you intend to translate into English answers to questions in Italian too? And the question too?

Only translating the top answer (or two) would be manageable.

Apparently, they changed idea before even starting.

I don't see any reason why not. Indeed the consensus on this question seems to be that translations are desirable, but are done on a case by case basis due to the amount of work required.
That said, as for all things liable to flood the start page, I would recommend not editing more than two questions a day.

An additional note: I took it for granted, but of course the original text should be preserved (that is the post should contain both the Italian and the English version as in this case).

That's a good point. Touching too many questions could cause new content to fall off the front page.
